# append span element and fadeOut jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadeout

I'm developing a validation function for an input field that only takes in digits. If it's not a number, it is aupposed to append a span with a message: "Only digits" and then fadeout. The problem is that both the input field and the span fades away.

How do I make it ao that only the message fades out?

```
</head>
<body id="test">
Number : <input type="text" title="numInput" name="quantity" id="quantity"   maxlength="8" />&nbsp;

</body>
</html>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('input[title="numInput"]').keypress(function (e) {
 //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
 if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {

var errmsg = "<span>Only digits</span>";

  $("#test").append(errmsg).show().fadeOut("slow");
           return false;
 }

 });
});
```

Comment: because you are fading out the test which contains the input and the span

Comment: give the error message a class or an id and fade that out instead of the whole body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('input[title="numInput"]').keypress(function(e) {
    //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
    if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {

      $(".error").fadeIn("slow").fadeOut("slow");
      return false;
    }

  });
});
```

```css
.error{display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body id="test">
  Number : <input type="text" title="numInput" name="quantity" id="quantity" maxlength="8" />&nbsp;
<span class="error">Only digits</span>
</body>
```

1. Add the error message span in html
2. Add class to span then hide it in CSS
3. Then do fadein and fadeout

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('input[title="numInput"]').keypress(function(e) {
    //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
    if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {

      var errmsg = "<span id='spantoremove'>Only digits</span>";
      var thiscontext = $(this);

      $('#test').append(errmsg);
      setTimeout(function() {
        $("#spantoremove").remove()
      }, 3000);
      return false;
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body id="test">
  Number : <input type="text" title="numInput" name="quantity" id="quantity" maxlength="8" />&nbsp;
</body>
```

1. Try using settimeout.
2. After appending settimeout example 3 sec then remove

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfurtunatley in this project I'm not allowed to edit the html. I must append it through jQuery

Comment: @LittleBird try with set time out..you can add ID to specify which span to remove. Note i used remove so that it wont spam the span on every input

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use fade out separately by giving an id to the span tag because currently, it applies to the element with id test.
You can use input type number too for numeric values.
here is the running script.

```
var errmsg = "<span>Only digits</span>";
$("#test").append(errmsg);
document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].setAttribute("id", "errorMsg");
setTimeout(function(){ $("#errorMsg").fadeOut("slow"); }, 3000);
```

Comment: I tried it before but it something that I'm missing.
When I do this, nothing is happening:
var errmsg = "<span id="error">Only digits</span>";

 $("#test").append(errmsg);
 $("#error").show().fadeOut("slow");

Comment: try to use fade out with time out

Comment: here is the running code, you can refer it. : var errmsg = "<span>Only digits</span>";
$("#test").append(errmsg);
document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].setAttribute("id", "errorMsg");
setTimeout(function(){ $("#errorMsg").fadeOut("slow"); }, 3000);

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('input[title="numInput"]').keypress(function (e) {
 //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
 if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {

var errmsg = "<span>Only digits</span>";

  $("#test").append(errmsg);
  $(errmsg).fadeOut("slow");
           return false;
 }

 });
});



<div>
<div id="test">
Number : <input type="text" title="numInput" name="quantity" id="quantity"   maxlength="8" />&nbsp;

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that before, the error message don't disappear. It's supposed to fade away